# Multiple timestamps/datetime with default for SQL 5.5 AND 5.6

Tags: mysql, sql

Alright, I'm running into a problem with my SQL create table. I work off two different severs, a WAMP sever on my computer for testing, which runs sql 5.6 something, and my online host who don't update very often and are running off 5.5 something. Because of this I'm having a issues with my create table.

my table SQL looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table
(
user_id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
member_till DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
banned_till DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
status ENUM('inactive', 'active') DEFAULT 'inactive',

PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

This works on my localhost 5.6 server, but my online 5.5 server I get the error "#1067 - Invalid default value for 'member_till'" because 5.5 doesn't allow defaults on DATETIME fields.

So I tried this:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table
(
user_id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
member_till TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
banned_till TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
status ENUM('inactive', 'active') DEFAULT 'inactive',

PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

This works fine on my online 5.5 server, but on my local host 5.6 server when I try to insert a user I get the error "General error: 1364 Field 'member_till' doesn't have a default value".

So I need a solution that works on both servers. Honestly it doesn't matter what time stamp is placed in the fields as the default value is just a place holder, but it has to be valid date-time format that is on or before the sign up date.

P.S. The query is ran using a PHP PDO script encase that makes any difference.

Comment: MySQL or SqlServer? These are two entirely different products.

Comment: MySQL. Sorry, I Clicked the wrong tag.